# Where can I get a gesture file with all alphabets and numbers for android?

Tags: android, gesture, gesture-recognition

I'm trying to implement gesture search in my app. The gesture overlay detects the gesture and the prediction gives alphabets or numbers. The online search tell me to create a gestures file from gesture builder. I made a gesture file, but the alphabets are detected incorrectly. If someone could give me a link to some library for handwriting recognition in android. Or any other help that may improve the prediction.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone? Any help is appreciated!